# How to mount NAS volume via. Terminal /command line without additional prompts on OSX

Tags: macos, unix, mount

I remotely manage a Mac Mini at home when I am away. We also have a Synology NAS that I use for various additional storage and backups. Sometimes, if there is WiFi or internet issues, the Mac Mini will lose connection to the NAS and various backup tasks will no longer work.

As a result, when I am away, I would like to be able to re-mount the NAS Volume back to the Mac Mini using the command line as I can send this over using ARD.

However, currently, when I execute the following:

`open -jg /Volumes; open 'smb://USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER/Backup'`

It will mount it without the prompt but will pop-up the Finder for no reason.

Further, and more annoying, it will often pop-up a confirmation that says

> "You are attempting to connect to the server "SERVER". Click Connect
> to continue."

Which is annoying because I do not see this on the command-line side and need to then remote Screen Share to the computer to manually click the prompts.

Ideally I'd like it to just execute the mounting without really anything going on and disrupting what's happening on my system, popping up windows etc. or requiring confirmations.